# form action starts with "null"

Tags: jsf

I'm migrating an application from an old WebLogic to JBoss EAP 7.4, but ideally the application shouldn't be touched (other than switching from Ant to Maven). This application uses Facelets and javax.faces-api 2.1 (but this can be changed).
I am having issues with the `action` parameter inside a `form`.

The .xhtml page looks like this:

`<h:form id="search" onkeypress="submitOnEnter(event, this.id);">`

And the resulting .html page rendered by the browser looks like this:

`<form id="search" name="search" method="post" action="null/mywebapp/pages/mypage.xhtml" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" onkeypress="submitOnEnter(event, this.id);">`

That `action` is obviously wrong and the browser gets a `HTTP 404` error when trying to submit that form.

I tried switching to com.sun.faces:jsf-impl and jsf-api, I tried version 2.0, 2.1 and 2.2 of javax.faces-api, but I always get the same error.

Where does JSF get that `null` value? Shouldn't it be a simple postback to `mypage.xhtml`? How do I fix this?

Comment: Remove **all** manually included JSF libs and retry. JBoss EAP 7 already ships with JSF 2.x out the box and JSF 2.x has fine backwards compatibility. If this still fails you'll need to tell more about any custom JSF-related classes/libs/configuration which deviates from the default.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I added <scope>provided</scope> to the POM that needed JSF, and now the javax.faces library isn't in the EAR/lib dir anymore. The "null" issue is still present though. I found a class that extends ViewHandlerWrapper, specifically the method getActionURL(), could that be the culprit?

Comment: Undoubtedly. You'll have to revise/rewrite that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First remove all manually included JSF libs and retry. JBoss EAP 7 already ships with JSF 2.x out the box and JSF 2.x has fine backwards compatibility. If this still fails you'll need to re-analyze any custom JSF-related classes/libs/configuration which deviate from the default. You can usually find them (in)directly in the `faces-config.xml` file.

One of the direct causes could be a custom [`ViewHandler`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/8/apidocs/javax/faces/application/viewhandler) implementation which overrides the [`getActionURL()`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/8/apidocs/javax/faces/application/viewhandler#getActionURL-javax.faces.context.FacesContext-java.lang.String-) method in an incorrect manner. That's the one where the `<h:form>` obtains the action URL from.

Comment: Yes, I think that was the reason: there was a custom ViewHandler implementation.